# Is there a term for "two-faced" or "reverse-tsundere" characters?

Tags: tropes, lucky-star, oreimo

Is there a (Japanese) cultural term for reverse-tsundere-type or two-faced characters who are sweet on the outside, but mean people on the inside. Like Kanako from *Oreimo* and Akira from *Lucky Star*?

[image: Two-faced!]

[image: ...and Another one!]

Comment: Akira is a Nice Character Mean Actor according to TvTropes. Still don't know for it's Japanese equivalent.

Comment: And so is Kanako.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the term is still *tsundere*.

> The word is derived from the terms tsun tsun (ツンツン), meaning to turn away in disgust, and dere dere (デレデレ) meaning to become 'lovey dovey'.
>
> — [*Tsundere*, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere)

There are, then, two types of *tsundere*: *Tsun* (Type A), and *Dere* (Type B).

**Type A**, also known as **harsh**, is what we typically consider *tsundere*; they are typically angry, mean, or pessimistic on the outside, but have a sweet side that they reveal to characters they like (or in other similar situations).

**Type B**, also known as **sweet**, is the reverse of Type A. These characters are typically sweet and kind on the outside, but have a hidden meanness inside of themselves that they sometimes unleash, usually in a response similar to that of Type A.

Originally, the term seemed to refer to Type A only, but has expanded over the years:

> The term was originally used to describe characters who began with a harsh outgoing personality, but slowly revealed a soft and vulnerable interior over time. Over the years the character archetype has become flanderized, and is now generically associated with a character who flips between the two emotional states at the slightest provocation.
>
> — [*Tsundere*, TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Tsundere)

So, it seems the way the word *tsundere* is structured, it can have either *tsun* as the default mood, or *dere*, meaning it can be used to describe either variation of a character. In your case, though, you're looking for a "Type B *Tsundere*".

Comment: I agree. Though the term tsundere mostly refer to those characters with love interests. Note that `dere` means `lovestruck` or `lovey dovey`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *tsundere*, it's *haraguro* (腹黒).

It means a character who is "two-faced", acts nice but vicious with certain people or in secret.

Example of haraguro character: Maki from Seto no Hanayome.

Comment: The definition of [*haraguro*](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%85%B9%E9%BB%92%E3%81%84) is "wicked". Is there any reference to "acts nice"?

Comment: @AkiTanaka hara is the abdomen, the inside or interior, so haraguro is wicked on the inside: https://vndb.org/i1251.